# Java convert JSONObject to URL parameter

Tags: java, android, json, url, urlencode

What is the elegant way to convert [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) to URL parameters.
For example, JSONObject:

```
{stat: {123456: {x: 1, y: 2}, 123457: {z: 5, y: 2}}}}
```

this should be like:

```
stat[123456][x]=1&stat[123456][y]=2&stat[123457][z]=5&stat[123457][y]=2
```

of course with escaped symbols, and of course JSON object could be more complicated..
Maybe there already exist some mechanisms for that?

Thanks,

Comment: You could use an HTTP POST instead.

Comment: I'm using POST, but you have to pass parameters first...

Comment: I think Marcelo is suggesting that you send the actual JSON as your POST data. When using POST, it's not mandatory to use the `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format (i.e. `key=value`)

Answer (score 1):

If readability isn't a big concern, you could base64-encode the JSON string in the url, and then base64-decode inside the web server before decoding the JSON itself.

Comment: That looks like a custom format that is very unlikely to be supported by any general purpose library. You'll probably have to write an algorithm yourself.