# Java parse get params sent by jquery

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, post, get

**EDIT** Maybe this is better explanation (sorry, I know javascript better than English... and I don't know very well javascript :-)

I need to map a complex javascript object sent with jquery $.ajax in a java bean by my servlet.

This is a real example done with jQuery and sniffed with Firebug.
This is the js code:

```
$("#test").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/server", 
        data: { "data1": [{key:1, val:2},{key:3, val:4}] }, 
        type: "post",               
        }
    });
});
```

As you can see I'm sending a complex object inside $.ajax data, not a simple map.
If I check how the http request is sent with firebug sniffer i get this POST params:

```
Parameters application/x-www-form-urlencoded
data1[0][key]   1
data1[0][val]   2
data1[1][key]   3
data1[1][val]   4
```

This is how jquery convert a complex object into a simple map. I would like to get this object in a java bean.
Thanks.

**EDIT2**
This: [Java convert JSONObject to URL parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518323/java-convert-jsonobject-to-url-parameter) seems to be exactly the opposite of my demand. But it has no answer...

Answer (score 2):

This is JSON and you can use [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for mapping it to POJO. See [this tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/)

**Reading a HttpServletRequest**

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
SomeClass someClass = gson.fromJson(
        new InputStreamReader(httpServletRequest.getInputStream()), SomeClass.class);
```

**EDIT**

You may want to look at [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779251/convert-json-to-hashmap-using-gson-in-java) which should help you with mapping your JSON to POJO (or Java beans as you say).

**EDIT 2**

Try to add `processData` parameter and set it to `false`. This should prevent transforming of the given JSON into a query string.

```
$("#test").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
      url: "/server", 
      data: { "data1": [{key:1, val:2},{key:3, val:4}] }, 
      type: "post", 
      processData: false
  });
});
```

Comment: I already use Gson, but i think it can decode from a json string, do you mean that it can catch object also from http request params?

Comment: @Tobia I'm not quite sure what did you mean by _http request params_ but I updated my answer - see if it fits.

Comment: I tried to explain better editing my question, in your example seems that my httpServletRequest has a json string inside a not a get/post params

Comment: @Tobia That Firebug sniffer does not show how the HTTP request really looks like. The thing is that each requests consists of headers and data. And your _complex object_ is converted to JSON and sent in the data part. If you want to restore that object, you have to (not the only option) create POJOs and use the `InputStreamReader` to convert JSON from data part into a POJO.

Comment: @Tobia To make it clear - what you see in the Firebug sniffer is parsed and formatted HTTP request. In Java servlet you get the exact string as you have after `data:` in your JavaScript.

Comment: I already tried your code but It dosn't work. I get a com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 32. Infact if I write the requeste.getInputStream to a file i see the url ecoded vars as firefug shows to me, not a json string. To reach what you said I should encode object to json before the jquery request.

Comment: This is the request.getInputStream content: data1%5B0%5D%5Bkey%5D=1&data1%5B0%5D%5Bval%5D=2&data1%5B1%5D%5Bkey%5D=3&data1%5B1%5D%5Bval%5D=4

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11687/discussion-between-tomas-and-tobia)

Comment: This doesn't work, jquery dosn't start the request with processData false

Comment: @Tobia why not? maybe there is another problem... I think you have useless `}` in there... It seems so... Check your JS console for errors

Comment: Plese try my jquery code with "processData:false" you will find what it does not send request.